# White space in CollectionView

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

I have a CollectionView with some elements. Above the CollectionView, at the bottom of the page I have a button. When we do the scrolling I would like that after the last element of the CollectioView there was some empty space, so as to correctly display all the elements. I don't know how to implement it.

**this is my XAML code**

```
 <CollectionView               
        x:Name="CategoryView" 
        RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint="{ConstraintExpression
        Type=RelativeToParent,
        Property=Width,
        Factor=1}"
        RelativeLayout.YConstraint="{ConstraintExpression
        Type=Constant,
        Constant=160}"             
        Margin="10,0,10,0"
        HeightRequest="590"
        SelectionMode="Multiple"
        SelectionChanged="CategoryView_SelectionChanged">
        <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
            <GridItemsLayout Orientation="Vertical" Span="2" VerticalItemSpacing="3" HorizontalItemSpacing="4"/>
        </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
        <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="38"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="38"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                   
                    <Image Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.Column="0" Source="{Binding Image}"/>
                    <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0"  Text="{Binding Titolo}" FontSize="19" FontAttributes="Bold" TextColor="White" Margin="13,0,0,0"/>
                    <Image Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Source="checked.png" IsVisible="{Binding Vis}"/>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
    </CollectionView>
    <Button
        x:Name="ButtonInizia"
        RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint="{ConstraintExpression
        Type=RelativeToParent,
        Property=Width,
        Factor=1}"
        RelativeLayout.YConstraint="{ConstraintExpression
        Type=Constant,
        Constant=670}"
        Clicked="ButtonInizia_Clicked"
        HorizontalOptions="Center"
        BackgroundColor="Blue"
        Text="INIZIA"
        FontSize="16"
        TextColor="White"
        FontAttributes="Bold"
        HeightRequest="60"
        WidthRequest="300"/>
```

[image: the collectionView stops there]

Comment: Just add a bottom-margin to the `CollectionView`.

Comment: Or are you asking how to make the button appear fixed to the bottom of the view? In which case use a `DockPanel`.

Comment: Even I add the bottom-margin to the collectionView doesn't change

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can put the Button in the Footer of the Collectionview . Ad the end of the items in the CollectionView there is a Button.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/collectionview/layout#headers-and-footers

```
<CollectionView.Footer>
            <StackLayout BackgroundColor="LightGray">
                <Button Margin="10,0,0,0"
                       Text="Friends of Xamarin Monkey"
                       FontSize="Small"
                       FontAttributes="Bold"
                        Clicked="Button_Clicked"/>
            </StackLayout>
        </CollectionView.Footer>
```

Comment: I would like the button to always stay on top. But you gave me an idea. I solved it by inserting a transparent button in the CollectionView.Footer, in this way I can slide it higher

Comment: used a Button in the Footer before and when i read your post , maybe this is something that you could use also